# Improve mysql Speed?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, performance, process

I have mysql/php script running on my linux machine. Its basically migrating files content to MySql table. there are about 4400,000 Files, Account files each file`s content is places in a table in one row. It have been 14 hours and so far it have only done  300,000 Accounts.

At first it was very fast and was doing about 1000 files a second now it's slowed down to 50 files per second and the mysql process is consuming 95% of server CPU.

Although The machine have multiple cores and I was thinking if its possible to allocate more then one core to mysql process which is consuming 95% of CPU. 
Or is there any other way to make the process faster?

Thank you.

here is the script
https://paste.ee/p/LZwlH#GHxpgqiUUPsVQFchdKVny2DEJQxaXH9V

Comment: You need to show MySQL table structure/indexes, the code that's executing, the queries that are being executed, etc. Without code/table schema, it's anybody's guess as to what the problem is.

Comment: I have added the Link to the script paste. please check, Thanks

Comment: Still no table schema. Is `p_name` indexed? As the table grows, if it's not, your `SELECT` query will get slower and slower and slower. And don't use `SELECT *` if you don't actually need *all* the columns. If you just need to check if the record exists, select the primary key instead.

Comment: Thank you @Marcus the issue have been resolved. Indexed the p_name and Selected it instead of whole table..

Comment: What PHP, Mysql and Linux versions do you use ?

Comment: Myself ; I had MYSQL 5.6 and was slow for big and long requests... after changing for MariaDB 10 it did a big speed increase ;)

Comment: I also recommand looking at optimizing your my.conf (Mysql configuration file) see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CqMv0ucqFA for more details

Comment: Thanks @JohnR ! Really appriciate that altough the query is more than 1 year old but i would check out optimization reasource for my future reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* use the `mysql_*` API.  Switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Please provide these:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
```

`select * from players where p_name='` -- there is no need to select `*`, simply `SELECT 1`.  Do you have an index on `p_name`?  That is very important.

It smells like index updating, but can't be sure.

One way to speed up inserts is to 'batch' them -- 100 rows at a time will typically run 10 times as fast as 1 at a time.

Even better might be to use `LOAD DATA`.  You may need to load into a temp table, then massage things before doing `INSERT .. SELECT ..` to put the data into the real table.

Temporarily remove the `INSERT` from the procedure.  See how fast it runs.  (You have not 'proven' that `INSERT` is the villain.)